# How do I draw only part of a possibly large and/or zoomed SVG?

Tags: android, bitmap, svg, zooming

I would like to show a zoomable and scrollable map-like SVG in my app. The only way to do this without writing your own library etc. is to use an existing library all of which seem to render the SVG to a `Bitmap`, which can be assigned to an `ImageView`, for example.

The underlying bitmap quickly gets very large which may result in an out-of-memory exception. How do I draw only part of a possibly large and/or zoomed SVG to a `Bitmap`? Scaling up a small bitmap looks bad and is not an option.

I am going to answer this question myself because i have been looking for an answer for a while, found it scattered all over the web (but not here) and think that it may be helpful for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not use Google's [svg-android](http://code.google.com/p/svg-android/) library? You can [scale](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#scale%28float,%20float%29) the `Canvas` to the correct size before rendering.

Comment: It seems that Google's svg-android renders the SVG at the size specified in the SVG document. There seems to be no way to specify the resolution I want. Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You do this by scaling the canvas before drawing.

Comment: When I get to the point when I actually draw the SVG on the screen, it has already been rasterized. Scaling the `Canvas` results in a pixelated image which is something I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Turns out Graham is right: svg-android produces `SVG` objects which provide a `PictureDrawable` via `createPictureDrawable()`. `Pictures`record drawing operations (Canvas API) and thus do not pixelate when the canvas is scaled. Should have taken your answer "more seriously" before, would have saved a lot of time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Would this be like how Google maps works?  They appear to tile and increase/decrease detail as you zoom in and out.

I have done something similar in the past, not sure if it is how Google did it but my scheme worked exceptionally well for me. What I did was break my map into rectangular regions, I would then calculate which regions had any portion that was visible and pull in data only from those regions.  Each rectangular region was sub-divided to provide more detail if the user zoomed in.  I kept subdividing down to the level I wanted, I stopped at three, because I used a 10 X 10 grid so each level was effectively a magnification of 10 - at level three I was viewing 100 times the detail I was viewing at level one which was sufficient for my needs.

I was even able to animate this so that when you zoomed in you appeared to smoothly "fly" closer to the terrain.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I am using [libsvg-android](https://launchpad.net/libsvg-android) which requires the NDK but which seems to be very fast, especially if you have to redraw your SVG frequently. Actually, I am using [this modified version](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/136239/Android-ImageView-and-Drawable-with-SVG-Support) of the library which enables you to query the width and height of the SVG as specified in the SVG document.

My first approach was this:

```
long svgID = SvgRaster.svgAndroidCreate();
SvgRaster.svgAndroidParseBuffer(svgID, svgString);
SvgRaster.svgAndroidSetAntialiasing(svgID, true);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(500, 500, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
SvgRaster.svgAndroidRenderToAreaUniform(svgID, new Canvas(bitmap), -300, -200, 1500, 1500);
```

First, the SVG source is parsed. Then, a `Bitmap` is created that will be assigned to an `ImageView` later on. Next, the SVG is rendered (zoomed to 1500x1500 pixels in size) to the bitmap. Note the translation (-300, -200) applied because the user has scrolled the image view.

This does not work. It seems that negative offsets are not supported.

Instead, the canvas has to be translated like this:

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
canvas.translate(-300, -200);
SvgRaster.svgAndroidRenderToAreaUniform(svgID, canvas, 0, 0, 1500, 1500);
```

This works as expected. The translation of the SVG is applied to the canvas; the scale is applied by adjusting the size of the rendered SVG. In this way, you can have a large SVG document and render the proportion you are interested in to a much smaller bitmap.

I've written an `ImageView` subclass which is scrollable in both the x and the y directions and zoomable. Its image resource is a low resolution raster image of the SVG. When the user scrolls or zooms the image, this version of the SVG is shown. When the user stops interacting with the image, I render the currently visible part of the SVG to a `Bitmap` the size of my image view and draw this instead of the low resolution image.

Comment: NOTE: libsvg is GPL (i.e. you cannot use it in most projects), whereas all the others are BSD/Apache/LGPL or similar. It appears to be the best implementation, but it's the odd one out for licensing. Fine for some people, but easy to overlook if you're careless.